# Are any of the Yakuza that Ronin attacks from “The Wolverine”?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, x-men-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame, the-wolverine

I recognized a few faces of the Yakuza people that Ronin attacks in *Avengers: Endgame*.

Is this intentional cross-seed of *The Wolverine* possibly?

Comment: Sound confuisng

Comment: It's more likely that there are limited number of stunt men, actors and extras of Japanese ethnicity and they have simply been cast in both films than an intentional tie-in.

Comment: please be more elaborate with your question so that it can get the right people to answer it.

Answer (score 2):

Highly unlikely.

The actor you might have recognized is [Hiroyuki Sanada](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0760796/?ref_=ttfc_fc_cl_t4), who in *Endgame* plays Akihiko, the only Yakuza who stays alive long enough for us to see his face. In *The Wolverine*, Sanada was playing Shingen Yashida, Mariko's father, who had more of a role already.

But apart from the fact that they're played by the same actor, there is no real reason to think they're related:

- Comics-wise, Akihiko has a grand total of one single appearance (*Nick Fury* #2, 2017). Shingen Yashida is more prominent but the two have no connection that I know of;
- Marvel Cinematic Universe and X-Men Cinematic Universe aren't the same (yet). So characters from one aren't related to characters from the other - if you want to go down the "played by the same actor" road, remember that Chris Evans (Captain America) technically played the Human Torch some years back;
- Shingen Yashida died in *The Wolverine* and has no particular reason to pop up in an unrelated *Avengers* movie.

Comment: I understood his name was Akihito during the movie :/

Comment: @Taladris Sanada is listed as "Akihiko" on IMDb and Akihito doesn't ring a bell in Marvel universe (doesn't mean there isn't though). Maybe there were both an Akihiko and an Akihito in the same scene? A Yakuza shouts "he killed ____" (Akihito ?) If memory serves

Comment: that was a joke. Akihito is the Emperor of Japan (until early May).

Comment: @Taladris [completely missed the joke](https://i0.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/newsfeed/000/992/383/5f9.gif) :-)